# Jquery Custom Rightclick with open in new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

i was create a custom right click menu so one of the items is open in new tab with id 
`gm`
i want create a jquery function to open a mouseover links in new tab 
i was tried but it just open current link in new tab
any suggestion why it doesn't work  the below is my function

```
$("#gm").click(function(){
    window.open($("a[href^='http']").attr('href'));
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Give `target=_blank` for opening it in a new tab

Answer (score 0):

You need contextmenu event:

```js
$("#gm").on('contextmenu', function() {
    // window.open will not work because of SO iframe sandbox
    alert($(this).attr('href'));
    return false;
});
```

```html
<a id="gm" href="https://jquery.com">jquery home page</a>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: my function is good just i want on click open a mousever link not current opened link

Comment: @ZanyariGring use your function instead of mine but use contextmenu event instead of this click. This how you use right click. I couldn't use your function because `window.open` don't work on Stack Overflow snippets. As you can see if you run the snippet it show alert or open url depend on button you click, right or left.